# Python: get most recent date per company

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples, which consists of a date and a name of a company. A company can have info listed for multiple dates:

```
 [(Company A, datetime.date(1980,1,30)),
  (Company A, datetime.date(1990,1,30)),
  (Company B, datetime.date(1990,1,30)),
  (Company B, datetime.date(2000,1,30))]
```

What I want to do, is have a list that only includes the most recent date available for each company, ie the result:

```
 [(Company A, datetime.date(1990,1,30)),
  (Company B, datetime.date(2000,1,30))]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what have you tried so far, we need code to work with. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I’m thinking it’s something with list comprehension, but I’m a bit lost.  Maybe starting with [(i,j) for i,j in company if max(j) for set (i)]

Comment: We don't want to write the code for you. Where's the fun in that? But I suggest you look at `reduce`.

Answer (score 3):

how about using a `groupby` from itertools, then taking the max:

```
import datetime
x = [('Company A', datetime.date(1980,1,30)),
  ('Company A', datetime.date(1990,1,30)),
  ('Company B', datetime.date(1990,1,30)),
  ('Company B', datetime.date(2000,1,30))]

import itertools
out = []
for k,g in itertools.groupby(sorted(x, key = lambda y: y[0]), lambda y: y[0]):
    out.append(max(g, key = lambda y:y[1]))

out
[('Company A', datetime.date(1990, 1, 30)),
 ('Company B', datetime.date(2000, 1, 30))]
```

Comment: The problem with `groupby` is that it expects members of the same group to be contiguous. Compare the result of `list(groupby('abcabcabc'))` to that of `list(groupby('aaabbbccc'))`. The scheme you propose will fail if there's no guarantee that the list's elements are grouped by company. In your specific example, if you swap the middle two elements in `x` you will end up with 4 elements in `out`.

Comment: A sort will solve the semantic problem, but it does increase the algorithmic complexity of the solution from *O(n)* to *O(n log n)*. So, if your datasets are big enough, and you do this often enough in your program, it might just make it significantly more costly than finding a linear solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a dictionary ...

```
data = [('Company A', '1980,1,30'),
  ('Company A', '1990,1,30'),
  ('Company B', '1990,1,30'),
  ('Company B', '2000,1,30')]

datadict = { a:b for a,b in data }

for a, b in data:
    datadict[a] = max(b, datadict[a])

print(datadict)
```

Comment: By using `dict` as a variable, you are shadowing the built-in `dict`: shadowing built-ins is not a good idea.

Comment: If you *really* need the results in a list of pairs, then just use `datadict.items()` in Python 2, or `list(datadict.items())` in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using `reduce()`:

```
import datetime

company_dates = [
  ('Company A', datetime.date(1980,1,30)),
  ('Company A', datetime.date(1990,1,30)),
  ('Company B', datetime.date(1990,1,30)),
  ('Company B', datetime.date(2000,1,30)),
]

def reducer(acc, company_date):
  try:
    acc[company_date[0]] = max(acc[company_date[0]], company_date[1])
  except KeyError:
    acc[company_date[0]] = company_date[1]

  return acc

sorted = reduce(reducer, company_dates, {})

print sorted.items()
```

Here's another alternative solution using different functions:

```
import datetime
import operator

company_dates = [
  ('Company A', datetime.date(1980,1,30)),
  ('Company A', datetime.date(1990,1,30)),
  ('Company B', datetime.date(1990,1,30)),
  ('Company B', datetime.date(2000,1,30)),
]

sorted = sorted(company_dates, key=operator.itemgetter(0, 1), reverse=True)
unique = set([company_date[0] for company_date in sorted])
top = [next(c for c in sorted if c[0] == company) for company in unique]

print top
```